# Multiple jQuery Date inputs on one razor page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

So im generating datepickers on multiple items within my mvc page (an undefined amount based on data from a previous page.

Currently only the last textbox has the datepicker available on it.

I generate a datepicker function for each of the items first.

```
  @for (int p = 0; p < Model.InputParameters.Count; p++)
  {
      if (Model.InputParameters[p].DatePicker))
      {
            var name2 = "#datepicker"+p;

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var jsondetail2 = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(name2))';
                var newname2 = JSON.parse(jsondetail2);
                $(function () {
                    $(newname2).datepicker();
                });
            </script>
      }
}
```

Then later draw them out.

```
 var id = "datepicker" + i;
 @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => Model.InputParameters[i].Value, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @id = id})
```

There are no errors in firebug, the javascript gets generated for each of the datepickers but only the last one drawn ever fires.  Im stumped, still learning javascript so any explanations with answers will be appreciated!  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling around this solved it.

Generating each textbox in my for loop as follows.

```
         var id = "datepicker" + i;
         @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => Model.InputParameters[i].Value,DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @id = id, @class = "datepicker"})
```

And the new javascript (the doc ready is required for IE6,7)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepicker').each(function () {
            $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your scrips are executing but cannot find any textboxes on which to bind the DatePicker (i.e. the scripts fire *before* the inputs have been generated so the jQuery selector can't find the inputs) . You need a restructure, something like:

```
@for (int p = 0; p < Model.InputParameters.Count; p++)
{
  if (Model.InputParameters[p].DatePicker))
  {
       var id = "datepicker" + p.ToString();
       @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => Model.InputParameters[p].Value, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @id = id})

       <script type="text/javascript">
           //var jsondetail2 = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(name2))';
           var newname2 = "#@(Html.Raw(id))";//JSON.parse(jsondetail2);
           $(function () {
               $(newname2).datepicker();
           });
       </script>
  }
}
```

Comment: I had previously tried something similar and ive just given this a go, still only the last box seems to pop up the datepicker.  The generated html etc looks fine, the ids match up, nothing in firebug...